# Wordpress file_put_contents on save_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to write to a file when I save a post in WP. This is just a basic example-- I'll be writing a bunch of other content to this file, not just the date.  That being said, this basic example is not working. Setting an absolute path did not help either.

The update_post_meta is just there to verify that the function did indeed run.

```
function add_info() {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $file = "latest.json";
    file_put_contents($file, $date);

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'latest', $date );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_info', 10, 3 );
```

Also, neither 'save_post' nor 'post_updated' work, but 'after_setup_theme' does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I needed absolute path back to the server root:

```
$file = ABSPATH . 'latest.json';
```

or

```
$file = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . 'latest.json';
```

Answer (score 0):

pass in $post_id to your function

```
function add_info($post_id) {
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   $file = "latest.json";
   file_put_contents($file, $date);

   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'latest', $date );
}
```